# Swift UITableview Custom Cell with multiple section array and row data array Search Implementation

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create `UITableview` custom cell with multiple section and cell. Here, I would like to add two things check mark and `search` option both I tried by using below code but not working both.

Below my Code. How to fix this?

```
class  CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CountLabel: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!
    let sectionData = ["1", "2"]
    let rowNames = [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
    var filteredData: [[String]]!
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filteredData = rowNames
}


//MARK: List Tableview
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionData[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell
        cell.NameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

//MARK: Search Delegate

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? rowNames : rowNames.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
                return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            })
            Self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sectionData = filteredData before tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I am facing error - **Value of type '[String]' has no member 'range'** at  return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil line. also I would like to use better code for this.

Comment: datastring.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())

Comment: filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? projects : projects.filter({(dataString: [String]) -> Bool in
                return dataString.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }) Showing error Value of type '[String]' has no member 'lowercased' @AlexandrKolesnik

Comment: in question you dataString: String in comment dataString: [String] it is important for search, in case of array you should do smth like dataString.first(where: { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})

Comment: @dahiya_boy Its different question and also my scenario totally different man. why you did duplication remark.

Comment: @dahiya_boy NO buddy. Its not same. I will improve my content

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to replace

```
let sectionData = ["1", "2"]
let rowNames = [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
```

with

```
let tableViewData = ["1": ["A", "B", "C"], "2": ["D", "E", "F"]]
```

Declare `filteredData` as `[String:[String]]?`, not `[[String]]!`.

Then you can filter `tableViewData` with the following code:

```
filteredData = tableViewData.compactMapValues { currentSection -> [String]? in
    let filteredRow = currentSection.filter {
        $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
    return filteredRow.isEmpty ? nil : filteredRow
}
```

Add new property `var filteredDataKeys: [String]?` and update it each time after you update `filteredData`: `filteredDataKeys = filteredData?.keys.sorted()`

And use the following `UITableViewDataSource` methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return filteredDataKeys?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return filteredDataKeys?[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let keyForSection = filteredDataKeys?[section] else {
        return 0
    }
    return filteredData?[keyForSection]?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell
    guard let keyForSection = filteredDataKeys?[indexPath.section] else {
        return cell
    }
    let textForRow = filteredData?[keyForSection]?[indexPath.row]
    cell.NameLabel.text = textForRow
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy great solution. Btw can you update by using Struct because I am going to use for this JSON data load in future. @Roman Podymov

Comment: Thanks @Roman Podymov BTW We can't assign return 0 inside numberofrows guard let keyForSection = filteredData?.keys.sorted()[indexPath.section] else {
        return 0
    }

Comment: @BenDev Why not? As I understood if `searchText == "G"` there will be no rows in the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197350/discussion-between-ben-dev-and-roman-podymov).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some changes like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

var searchController : UISearchController!
var rowNames = [[(value: "A",selected: false),(value: "B",selected: false),(value:"C",selected:false)],[(value: "D",selected: false),(value: "E",selected:false),(value:"F",selected:false)]]
var filteredData: [[(value:String,selected:Bool)]]!
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //filteredData = rowNames
}


//MARK: List Tableview
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return rowNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return (section + 1).description
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.searchBar.text != nil && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filteredData.count
    }else{
        return rowNames[section].count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell
    if searchController.searchBar.text != nil && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
         cell.NameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].value
    }else{
        cell.NameLabel.text =  rowNames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].value
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if searchController.searchBar.text == nil || searchController.searchBar.text == ""{
        if rowNames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected == true{
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
            rowNames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected = false
        }else{
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            rowNames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].selected = true
        }
    }

    //self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

//MARK: Search Delegate

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        })
      filteredData =  rowNames.map({row in
            row.filter({
                $0.value.contains(searchText)
            }).map({$0})
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}
since you are setting a checkmark on the cell selected you must keep a track of it state in your dataSource. so that's why the model change to a tupple if you use a struct you can add a sleceted field and be always false, in your

**didSelectRow** function you have to track the state of the model to show or no the checkmark. and the search is not worth searching is there is not text for search so the app should not reload the tableView.

Comment: I think section.description missing @kjoe

Comment: Thanks I will check it. but still I didn't get perfect answer buddy because I am going to load JSON data so if anyone used struct with explanation. It will be more better @kjoe

Comment: man then you sould post a question with a struc and json struc not relative data, you want a answer for a no asked question, try to post a MVP in github for asesoration, since this code is almost a portion of code donde with struc and json